# Sortable QBoxLayout

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list of QGroupBoxes and I want them to be "sortable" as in drag and drop to another order. Very much like QListView does it with InternalMove.

Is it possible to do this *without* reinventing the wheel one more time?
I do know I could do it myself with drag and drop, but with nice position indicators while dragging etc it's not something one without much qt experience can finish in just a few hours. I've already looked at how QListView does it but it seems to implement it completely from scratch, or is there an easy way for me to use any of it?

Another idea I had was to actually use a QListView but it doesn't seem to be that simple to put QGroupBoxes in there. I tried subclassing QStyledItemDelegate and while painting works quite fine I have trouble with the editor - I guess I would ideally return a copy of my groupbox in createEditor? But it's been two hours since I had the idea and it's far from working.

btw, this is not a duplicate of [Sortable QHBoxLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4672522/sortable-qhboxlayout) - completly different issue

Comment: If you want to leverage something, then QListView is the only thing to leverage you've got. Either it'll work, or you'll have to reinvent it. The layouts are not meant to support any user interaction directly.